# Python - tuple unpacking in dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable-unpacking, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to write a function that turns strings of the form `'A=5, b=7'` into a dict `{'A': 5, 'b': 7}`. The following code snippets are what happen inside the main `for` loop - they turn a single part of the string into a single dict element.

This is fine:

```
s = 'A=5'
name, value = s.split('=')
d = {name: int(value)}
```

This is not:

```
s = 'A=5'
d = {name: int(value) for name, value in s.split('=')}
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Why can't I unpack the tuple when it's in a dict comprehension? If I get this working then I can easily make the whole function into a single compact dict comprehension.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your code, `s.split('=')` will return the list: `['A', '5']`.  When iterating over that list, a single string gets returned each time (the first time it is `'A'`, the second time it is `'5'`) so you can't unpack that single string into 2 variables.

You could try:  `for name,value in [s.split('=')]`

More likely, you have an iterable of strings that you want to split -- then your dict comprehension becomes simple (2 lines):

```
 splitstrs = (s.split('=') for s in list_of_strings) 
 d = {name: int(value) for name,value in splitstrs }
```

Of course, if you're obsessed with 1-liners, you can combine it, but I wouldn't.

Answer (score 9):

Sure you could do this:

```
>>> s = 'A=5, b=7'
>>> {k: int(v) for k, v in (item.split('=') for item in s.split(','))}
{'A': 5, ' b': 7}
```

But in this case I would just use this more imperative code:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for item in s.split(','):
        k, v = item.split('=')
        d[k] = int(v)


>>> d
{'A': 5, ' b': 7}
```

Answer (score 6):

Some people tend to believe you'll go to hell for using `eval`, but...

```
s = 'A=5, b=7'
eval('dict(%s)' % s)
```

Or better, to be safe (thanks to mgilson for pointing it out):

```
s = 'A=5, b=7'
eval('dict(%s)' % s, {'__builtins__': None, 'dict': dict})
```

Comment: You could make it a little safer: `eval('dict(%s)'%s,{'__builtins__':None,'dict':dict})`  -- I think using this will close the vulnerabilities from injection type attacks (although I'd love to hear via a (preferably friendly) comment if I'm wrong about this).

Answer (score 3):

See mgilson answer to why the error is happening. To achieve what you want, you could use:

```
d = {name: int(value) for name,value in (x.split('=',1) for x in s.split(','))}
```

To account for spaces, use `.strip()` as needed (ex.: `x.strip().split('=',1)`).

Answer (score 2):

How about this code:

```
a="A=5, b=9"
b=dict((x, int(y)) for x, y in re.findall("([a-zA-Z]+)=(\d+)", a))
print b
```

Output:

```
{'A': 5, 'b': 9}
```

This version will work with other forms of input as well, for example

```
a="A=5 b=9 blabla: yyy=100"
```

will give you

```
{'A': 5, 'b': 9, 'yyy': 100}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> strs='A=5, b=7'

>>> {x.split('=')[0].strip():int(x.split('=')[1]) for x in strs.split(",")}
{'A': 5, 'b': 7}
```

for readability you should use normal for-in loop instead of comprehensions.

```
strs='A=5, b=7'
dic={}
for x in strs.split(','):
  name,val=x.split('=')
  dic[name.strip()]=int(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Since Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions), you can use walrus operator (`:=`) for this kind of operation. It allows to assign variables in the middle of expressions (in this case, assign the list created by `.split('=')` to `kv`).

```py
s = 'A=5, b=7'
{(kv := item.split('='))[0]: int(kv[1]) for item in s.split(', ')}
# {'A': 5, 'b': 7}
```

One feature is that it leaks the assigned variable, `kv`, outside the scope it was defined in. If you want to avoid that, you can use a nested for-loop where the inner loop is over a singleton list (as suggested in mgilson's answer).

```py
{k: int(v) for item in s.split(', ') for k,v in [item.split('=')]}
```

[Since Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations), loops over singleton lists are optimized to be as fast as simple assignments, i.e. `y in [expr]` is as fast as `y = expr`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
>>> s
'a=5, b=3, c=4'
>>> {z.split('=')[0].strip(): int(z.split('=')[1]) for z in s.split(',')}
{'a': 5, 'c': 4, 'b': 3}
```